# How to change value for parameter in BigQuery datatable with SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

**Situation**

I have a BigQuery datatable (004a-TWtweets-02) of Twitter posts (tweets).

For a given `tweet_id` parameter, I am trying to change the `score` value from **.3** to **.2**, which will then change a `sentiment2` value from `positive` to `neutral`.

**Attempted solution**

I'm using this BQ SQL:

```
UPDATE `pp-004a.004a02.004a-TWtweets-02` SET score=2 WHERE tweet_id=1525524602327379969;
```

**Results**

That worked for the `score` parameter, as when I search for that tweet:

```
SELECT * FROM `pp-004a.004a02.004a-TWtweets-02` WHERE tweet_id=1525524602327379969
```

I found the new `score` value to be '2'.

**Error**

However, when I try to update the calculation for the `sentiment2` parameter across the entire datatable, per below …

```
UPDATE
 'pp-004a.004a02.004a-TWtweets-02'
SET
 sentiment2 =
 CASE
   WHEN score<=-0.3 THEN 'Negative'
   WHEN score>=0.3 THEN 'Positive'
 ELSE
 'Neutral'
END
WHERE
 TRUE
```

… the same `tweet_id` value `1525524602327379969` still has a `sentiment2` value of `positive`, when it should be `neutral` based on the new score being below the positive threshold of 3.

Is there something I'm overlooking here?

Comment: Shouldn’t it be a set score = .2 instead?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I'm wanting it to be neutral if it's between -.3 and .3, so the new value i've set for `score` is 2. Which should be `neutral`, right?

Comment: `2` is NOT between `-.3` and `.3` - that was my point!